# Cascading DropDown gracefully catch error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I have 5 cascading drop downs on my page.
I'd like them to **try** cascade, but if it doesn't cascade - gracefully stop trying or erroring-out.
I would also like all of the comboboxes to be enabled, rather than be disabled until the previous combobox is filled.

I've tried to .Enable(true) on the enabled fluent API, but the dropdowns are still disabled. Any idea how I can go about doing this?

```
   <div class="span5">
              <div class="control-group">
        @Html.Label("Product Types", new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls">
            @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                .Name("drpProductTypes")
                .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.drpProductTypes))
                .Placeholder("Select Category...")
                .CascadeTo("drpClass1").Enable(true)
            )
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.Label("Class 1", new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls">
        @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                .Name("drpClass1")
                .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("_GetDropDownClassOne", "List"))
                .Placeholder("Select Class 1...")
                .CascadeTo("drpClass2").Enable(true)
        )
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.Label("Class 2", new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls">
        @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                .Name("drpClass2")
                .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("_GetDropDownClassTwo", "List"))
                .Placeholder("Select Class 2...")
                .CascadeTo("drpClass3").Enable(true)
        )
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.Label("Class 3", new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls">
        @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                .Name("drpClass3")
                .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("_GetDropDownClassThree", "List"))
                .Placeholder("Select Class 3...")
                .CascadeTo("drpClass4").Enable(true)
        )
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.Label("Class 4", new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls">
        @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                .Name("drpClass4")
                .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("_GetDropDownClassFour", "List"))
                .Placeholder("Select Class 4...").Enable(true)
        )
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the cascading functionality if you do not want the disabled look - since this is by design.

You can implement that cascading manually with the help of the **change** event and the **dataBinding** event (to send the value of the other DropDownList through the e.data field if I remember correctly) and the **reload** method.

All of these methods and how they can be used you can find in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html).